# Export jar (eclipse) while keeping external lib and source files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to export my java project to be able to send it to a company in order to find a job. I use Eclipse Mars.

I'd like to send them source files, the (.json) file my program works on, an executable jar and the external library i'm using (json-simple-1.1).

I've tried this technique [Exporting a Java Project as .jar with including .java source code and preserving external libraries dependecies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113535/exporting-a-java-project-as-jar-with-including-java-source-code-and-preserving)
but it doesn't work for me, when I try to launch my project I get the following error

```
>>>java -jar projet.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

If you need more information, just ask me, I'll try to answer.

I'd like to apologize too because my question feels stupid... but I just can't find a solution...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just throwing in my two cents here... if you're applying for a job, using a build tool like maven is definitely a +1. Having your build dependent on your IDE's configuration is generally bad practice.

Comment: And if the company you are applying to uses a *different* build tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder inside your project (parallel to `src`) and add all external libraries to it. Reference these libraries in your project (by adding them to build path).

Include them in your jar while exporting it with runnable jar. It should work.

Note: Never use external jar files using absolute path in your project. Always use relative path reference, so that the project works fine when shipped somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already tried this solution. I have the following architecture: Project = src + doc + lib + myjsonfile.json.

Comment: How can I make eclipse use a relative path?

Comment: Under your eclipse project, look for reference libraries. Remove all the jar files. Now right click on jar files inside the lib folder under your project, select "build path" option and then click on "add to build path". All the jar files will be added with relative path.